# How to sign with RSA private PEM and SHA256 using C++ language?

Tags: c++, openssl

Does anyone know how to sign with RSA private PEM and SHA256 using the C++ language?

Like:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:20
```

This is my signing code:

```
const char *message = [signString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int messageLength = (int)strlen(message);
    
unsigned char sha256[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256((unsigned char *)message, messageLength, sha256);
    
unsigned char *sig = (unsigned char *)malloc(256);
unsigned int sig_len;
        
int rsa_sign_valid = RSA_sign(NID_sha256
                                  , sha256, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
                                  , sig, &sig_len
                                  , privateKey);
```

Comment: Title and body have "C", tag is "C++". Please decide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.